# bumblebee with nvidia-exxperimental-310 primus: failed to load any of the libraries

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, bumblebee

I have a dell inspirion 5720 with Intel HD 4000 with Nvidia GT 630M, running ubuntu 12.10 64bit.

I installed bumblebee first, and worked, after that primus, and it worked again.
After that I installed nvidia-experimental-310 (310.14) and changed both bumblebee.conf and the run file in /usr/bin/primusrun.

`optirun` runs fine and gained a 10 FPS boost
but `primusrun` gives this error:

```
$ primusrun glxspheres
primus: fatal: failed to load any of the libraries: /usr/lib/nvidia-experimental-310/libGL.so.1:/usr/lib32/nvidia-experimental-310/libGL.so.1
libnvidia-tls.so.310.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib32/nvidia-experimental-310/libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

i dont know why. and i followed this : http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/use-nvidia-experimental-drivers-310.html

here are my conf files:
`bumblebee.conf`: http://pastebin.com/tL0FVern
`/usr/bin/primusrun`:  http://pastebin.com/tP4PJpQS

Comment: I don't have experience with bumblebee, but i recommend to look at this. It is the new nvidia driver with optimus support ;).  https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/539249/unix-graphics-announcements-and-news/-linux-solaris-and-freebsd-driver-319-12-beta-/

Comment: I know about it, but i read it its still just initial support, and right now bumblebee has better support, so i wish to use bumblebee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this works, but I had the same problem and it worked when I did not replace the second path in the primus config file.

So I just used:

```
export PRIMUS_libGLa=${PRIMUS_libGLa:-'/usr/lib/nvidia-331/libGL.so.1:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1'}
```

or in your case, replace with:

```
export PRIMUS_libGLa=${PRIMUS_libGLa:-'/usr/lib/nvidia-experimental-310/libGL.so.1:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1'}
```